# I would like my image to zoom and then pan (only up and down) where the mouse cursor is

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have a gallery of my portfolio set-up. Once you click on the image, it makes a pop-up. Inside of the pop-up is the image and text describing the design, copywriting ect. Once you hover over the image, it zooms. My problem is that one or two of the images, on css hover transform scale, scales to such a size that it is outside of the viewing port of the browser. It is in rectangular form, where other designs are only square. I would like the user of the website to move their cursor up and have the image move with the cursor, so the user can see the top of the image, and then have the user move their cursor down to the bottom of the image and have the image move with the cursor so that the user can see the bottom of the image. I have no idea how to do this, and I've searched everywhere but I can not find anything useful. I think it might use background-image and java-script but I really need help since I don't have knowledge of this.

html:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/mainwebsite.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/fonts/futura_bold_stylesheet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/fonts/futura_book_stylesheet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/fonts/futura_light_bt-stylesheet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/fonts/futura_light_italic_stylesheet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/fonts/futura_medium_stylesheet.css">
    <script defer src="javascript/POPUP.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/Filters.js" defer></script>
    <script defer src="javascript/tothetop.js"></script>
    <script defer src="javascript/moveimage.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Ilana's creations</title>
</head>


<body class="helpme">
    
    <div class="container">
        
    <div class="mainnavbar">
        <div class="navbar_left">   
        <p class="nav">
            <a class="current" href="index.html">
                CREATIONS
            </a>
                </p>
        <p class="nav">
            <a href="aboutme.html">
                ABOUT ME
            </a>
                </p>
        <p class="nav">
            <a href="sayhi.html">
            SAY HI!
            </a>    
                </p>
        </div>
    
        <div class="navbar_right">
                <p class="nav1">
                    <a href= target="_blank">
            <img src="images/LI-In-Bug.png"  alt="LinkedIn" class="icon" style="width:20px;height:20px">
            </a>
            </p>
            <p class="nav1">
                Ilana van Rooyen
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    
    <div class="searchbar"  id="filtering">
    <button class="searchbarbuttons active" onclick="filterSelection('all')">
        ALL
        </button>
        <p class="search">
        |
        </p>
    <button class="searchbarbuttons" onclick="filterSelection('design')">
        DESIGN
        </button>
        <p class="search">
        |
        </p>
    <button class="searchbarbuttons" onclick="filterSelection('copy')">
        COPYWRITING
        </button>
        <p class="search">
        |
        </p>
    <button class="searchbarbuttons" onclick="filterSelection('creativewriting')">
        CREATIVE WRITING
        </button>
        <p class="search">
        |
        </p>
    <button class="searchbarbuttons" onclick="filterSelection('videos')">
        VIDEOS
        </button>
        <p class="search">
        |
        </p>
    <button class="searchbarbuttons" onclick="filterSelection('socialmedia')">
        SOCIAL MEDIA MANAGEMENT
        </button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="case">

            
        <!-- MODAL 22 BIGGER IMAGES -->
    
    <div class="nobutton design" data-modal-target="#modal22">
        <img src="Images/ZoetisMap_Pres.png" alt="ZoetisMap" width="250px" height="250px" class="gallerypics">
            </div>

        <div class="modal2" id="modal22" style="width: 50%; height: auto">
            
            
            <div id="scroll">
                <img src="Images/ZoetisMap_Design.png" alt="ZoetisMap" class="IMG3" style="width: 40%; height: 40%">
            </div>
            
            
        <div class="containerDB">
            
            <div class="DESC">
                <p class="DESC_text">
                    <strong class="title">
                    Layout design:
                        </strong>
                    Ilana van Rooyen
                </p>
                <p class="DESC_text"> 
                    <strong class="title">
                        Company:
                    </strong>
                    Agribonus
                </p>
                <p class="DESC_text">
                    <strong class="title">
                        Brief:
                    </strong>
                    Design a layout for an article provided by Zoetis for the Bonus magazine.  
                </p>
            </div>
            
            <div class="buttonclose">
                <button data-close-button class="closebutton">
                CLOSE
                </button>
            </div>
            
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
        
        <!-- OVERLAY JAVA -->
        
        <div id="overlay">
        </div>
    
        
        <!-- CLOSE DIV CASE -->
        
        </div>
            
        
    
    <div onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn"><img src="images/outline_expand_circle_down_black_24dp.png" alt="tothetop" height="80%" width="80%"></div>
    

    <div class="madewithlove" id="footer">
        <p class="love"><i> This website was made by me, with a lot of <b>love</b>, a lot of <b>googling</b>, and a lot of <b>banging my head on the table</b> (I'm fine, thanks).</i></p>

    </div>
     
    <!-- CLOSE DIV CONTAINER -->
        
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;  
    position: inherit;
}

strong {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: inherit;
}

p {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: inherit;
    margin: inherit;
    line-spacing: inherit;
}

.helpme {   
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    Display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.mainnavbar {
    color: white;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0.1px #707070;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px 0px 40px 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
}

.navbar_left {
    margin-left: 20%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-flex;
    font-family: 'futuralight';
    color: #707070;
    background-color: white;
}


.navbar_right {
    margin-right: 20%;
    float: right;
    display: inline-flex; 
    font-family: 'futuralight';
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #707070;
    background-color: white;
}

.nav {
    margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    background-color: white;
    transition-property: transform;
    transition: 0.25s ease;
}

.nav .current {
    font-family: 'futuramedium';
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.nav1 {
    margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
    background-color: white;
}

.nav::after {
  content: '';
  border-top: 1px solid #707070;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
  transition:transform 0.25s linear;
    
}
.nav:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
    font-family: 'futuramedium';
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.nav:hover::after {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
    
}


.icon:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1)
}

.searchbar {
    display: block;
    color: #707070;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px 20%;
}

.search {
    font-family: 'futuralight';
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #707070;
    margin: 0% 0% 8% 0%;
}

.searchbarbuttons {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    font-family: 'futuralight';
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #707070;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.searchbarbuttons:hover {
    font-family: 'futuramedium';
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.searchbarbuttons.active {
    font-family: 'futuramedium';
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.case {
    margin: 0px 20% 70px 20%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.gallerypics {
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.gallerypics:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5)
}

.nobutton {
    display: none;
    
}

.show {
    display: inline-block;
    transition: 0.3s;
    border-radius: 15px;
}


/* MODAL BIG IMAGES */

.modal2 {
    background-color: #CBCBCB;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    top: 10%;
    left: 23.9%;
    tranform: translate(-10%, -23.9%);
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}

.modal2.active {
    background-color: #CBCBCB;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    top: 10%;
    left: 23.9%;
    tranform: translate(-10%, -23.9%);
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.modal2 .IMG3 {
    object-fit: contain;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    border-radius: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.modal2 .IMG3:hover {
    cursor: zoom-in;
    transform: scale(170%);
    transition: 200ms ease-in;
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
    border-radius: 0px;

}


.modal2 .containerDB {
    object-fit: contain;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    float: right;
}

.modal2 .DESC {
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.modal2 .DESC_text {
    font-family: 'futuralight';
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #707070;
    line-height: 17pt;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.modal2 .DESC_text a:hover {
    font-family: 'futuramedium';
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #707070;
    line-height: 17pt;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.modal2 .title {
    font-family: 'futuramedium';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #707070;
    line-spacing: 20pt;
}

.modal2 .buttonclose {
    margin: 20px 0px;
}

.modal2 .closebutton {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    border: #707070;
    border-width: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: solid 1px #707070;
    background: white;
    font-family: 'futurabold';
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    font-size: 1.5vh;
    color: #707070;
    font-weight: normal;
    float: right;
}

.modal2 .closebutton:hover {
  transition:transform 0.25s linear;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #707070;
}

/* MODAL BIG IMAGES END */


#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #707070;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
}

#overlay.active {
    opacity:70%;
    pointer-events: all;
}

#myBtn {
  display: none; 
  position: fixed; 
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 30px; 
  border: none; 
  outline: none; 
  cursor: pointer;
}

#myBtn:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.madewithlove {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    box-shadow: -2px -2px 5px 0.1px #707070;
    height: 60px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: auto;
}   
    
.love {
    font-family: 'futuralight';
    color: #707070;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

javascript on pop-up only:

```
/* eslint-env es6 */
/* eslint-disable */
/* popup javascript */

const openModalButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-modal-target]')
const closeModalButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-close-button]')
const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay')

/* modal */

openModalButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const modal = document.querySelector(button.dataset.modalTarget)
    openModal(modal)
  })
})

/* close button modal */

closeModalButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const modal = button.closest('.modal2')
    closeModal(modal)
  })
})


function closeModal(modal) {
  if (modal == null) return
  modal.classList.remove('active')
  overlay.classList.remove('active')
}

function openModal(modal) {
  if (modal == null) return
  modal.classList.add('active')
  overlay.classList.add('active')
}

/* overlay open all */

overlay.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal2.active')
  modals.forEach(modal => {
    closeModal(modal)
  })
})
```

Images for download: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1OGD5iuyxcVekdr-pTjfkDi5o6uF4LVH5

Comment: please add some code to show us what you have :)

Comment: Please add some code so that people can help you figure out the issue.

Comment: thanks! I loaded the code-ing, unsure if it will help. I'm really freaking new at this.